# Class members only accessible from methods of the same class  - How?

Tags: c#, .net, properties

I've stumbled upon the following two "weird" looking properties:

```
Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule;

Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
```

These properties are a part of the class **Process** and **Assembly**, but the properties are only accessible from methods inside those classes.

Neither Private or Protected restricts properties to only being useable from methods inside the same class.

What do you call the protection level of these properties or how does this work at all?

Comment: Why do you say that `private` does not accomplish this? By your description, that's *exactly* what `private` does.

Comment: Both Process.MainModule and Assembly.Location are public and accessible to Methods in all classes.

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand your question, do you mean "why we can't write Process.MainModule; Assembly.Location; instead?" - if so, it is because MainModule and Location properties are not static/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GetExecutingAssembly is a **static** method that return a process Type, With this type you can access the **public** properties such as MainModule like this:

```
new Process().MainModule
```

So you confused a class and a object of that class.

Comment: +1 to @RedHat, that's what I mean in my comment to original question

Answer (score 3):

That is what private does

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121(v=vs.80).aspx

"Finally, a class or struct member can be declared as private with the private keyword, indicating that only the class or struct declaring the member is allowed access to that member."